# Pycharm IDE is not opening on my Windows 10..Badly need a Suggestion

Tags: python, pycharm

I used pycharm sometime after installing it for the first time on my windows 10(64 bit)..After some day i tried to open pycharm by double clicking(as usual we open softwares in our pc) but it is loading and after sometime the loading disappears..As this thing happens every time i tried opening pycharm i did the following things:

1. Restarted my Pc.
2. Reinstalled Pycharm
   But same problem is occurring.
   Badly need a help!

Comment: See if some of the suggestions on this page work: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207745045-PyCharm-not-opening-on-Windows-10 . If you can’t get it to work then I suggest you ask for help on Jetbrains’ forums.

Comment: When you uninstall and reinstall PyCharm it gives you the option of reusing the settings of a previous version or starting with new settings. Don't import the old settings, but start anew.

Comment: Also when you double click to start Pycharm, you can have a watch on your Task Manager, if it shows Pycharm is running then i would ask you to have some patience or try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem after reinstalling PyCharm in my Windows 10 Laptop.

Actually, I had to reset my Laptop due to some Startup problems which removed my previously working PyCharm IDE. After finishing reset of my Laptop, I reinstalled PyCharm and tried to open by double-clicking on Shortcut of its exe file, but failed several times.

Finally, I found a solution as follows:

Go to `C:\Users\<usrName>` folder and delete or rename `.PyCharm[Version.No]` folder. Then try to open PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in Windows 10 and the solution was, Go to the below path:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\JetBrains
```

and rename the folder of the current version `PyCharmCE2023.2` to `PyCharmCE2023.2_old` and then run PyCharm.